# writing comma separated values in jmeter to a txt file and then reuse them

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, post-processor

I want to fetch order id from a variable in loop and store them in txt file separated with a comma(eg:"12345,12346,12347) and then use all the values in one go.

I am getting following error while running the script :
**Error in method invocation: Method setout( java.io.PrintStream ) not found in class'bsh.Interpreter'
**'

[This is the variable ordid which i am storing in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3P6a.png)

Also it is creating the file in my system but giving error

[code i used to create a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38s8n.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo in your code, I believe it should be `setOut`
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
3. If you will execute your script with > 1 virtual user you will run into the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) as when 2 or more threads will be writing into the same file it will result in data corruption so consider using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) for storing the data